# Sharepoint Ribbon buttons doesn't apper in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, sharepoint-2010, ribbon

I have used out of the box sharepoint MasterPage and the ribbon buttons doesn't appear sometimes in **chrome**. Sometimes they will be disabled with grey color.
But works fine with Firefox and IE.

Any Idea....
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is now apparently supported by SharePoint, although I continue to have similar issues as you describe, the farms I work with are not patched to the latest CU though so if this is really important to you check the patch level and apply any outstanding commulative updates.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2012/04/04/updates-to-plan-browser-support.aspx

Also check this, apparently you need SP1 to support it:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/mickd/archive/2011/07/27/service-pack-1-sp1-for-microsoft-sharepoint-foundation-2010-and-microsoft-sharepoint-server-2010-white-paper.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use chrome extension that i mentioned [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92282/document-opened-for-editing-twice). I use it for datasheet view or if I need to login as a different user.